# Returning Item Attributes from Find Items Advanced API in eBay

Tags: javascript, api, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm making a call to the find items advanced api for eBay, based on a search query.

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html

My call looks something like this;

```
let url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced";
url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
url += "&categoryId=213"; // baseball
url += "&outputSelector(0)=PictureURLLarge";
```

This call returns the data fine, but not everything that I need and that I see available on eBay. I'm querying the baseball cards category and the one field i need (which is missing) is the Grade field. Notably, the attributes field is missing, thus guessing Grade might be in there?

I've gone through the documentation and really confused as to how to do this.

I know there is an outputSelector field which gets additional data, but I'm super confused as to whether or not this is the right way to go about getting what I need.

I tried using this with an aspectHistogram, but I don't think that is getting me what I need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think You need access to item's characteristics, so make use of Shopping API and method GetMultipleItems().

```
r={
   'ItemID': itemId_list,
   'IncludeSelector': 'ItemSpecifics'
}
response = api.execute('GetMultipleItems', r)
```

More details: https://github.com/Brat-Pit/eBay/blob/master/eBay_api.py